# Nested Loop or 'in', which is faster?

Tags: python, time, big-o

I am a python novice and was studying some basic coding challenges and was hoping to someone could explain which of the following snippets of code would run faster. The point is to see if there are pairs of integers within the list that add up to 100:

```
list = [1,2,3,99,5]
for i in list:
    for j in list:
       if i + j == 100:
          return True
```

or:

```
list = [1,2,3,99,5]
for i in list: 
    diff = 100 - i 
    if diff in list:
        return True
```

Comment: Look up TimeIt module and cProfile module to see how fast it runs and also what it does under the hood.

Comment: Both `in` and the `for` loop require an `O(n)` scan of the list, and both will break early if the item is found. You do fewer calculations in the latter, though, so I'd expect it to be a bit faster.

Comment: Although if you changed the list to a set, the second example should be faster.

Comment: Side note: **never** name your variable after a built-in. Use `lst` or `list_` instead.

Comment: Another side note: Study about `two pointer techniques`, it will help.

Comment: If you cared about performance (and had larger lengths), you wouldn't write *either* of these. Use a data type -- like a set or dictionary -- where a search is O(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Benchmark

This homemade, randomized benchmark demonstrates that the solution using `in` is significantly faster in most case. I did not investigate, but I did encounter some runs where the solution with the nested for-loops was slightly faster when toying with the sample size.

```
import time, random

def time_it(f, rep=100000):
    sample = [[random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(rep // 100)]

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(rep):
        f(sample[i % len(sample)])
    return (time.time() - start)

def nested_for(lst):
    for i in lst:
        for j in lst:
            if i + j == 100:
                return True

def nested_in(lst):
    for i in lst:
        diff = 100 - i
        if diff in lst:
            return True

print('for:', time_it(nested_for))
print('in:', time_it(nested_in))
```

#### Output

```
for: 0.7093353271484375
in: 0.24253296852111816
```

Removing the assignation of `j` on every iteration is probably what removes a big overhead in the solution with the `in`.

### Improvement

Although note that both solutions are *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. You can achieve *O(n)* by using a `set`. Since a `set` hashes its items, lookup is *O(1)*.

```
def contains_diff(lst):
    elements = set(lst)
    return any(100 - i in elements for i in elements)

print(contains_diff([1, 2, 3, 99])) # True
print(contains_diff([1, 2, 3])) # False
```

Interestingly enough, if you benchmark the above it will be generally slower than the `in` solution. This is because the probability of `in` finding a sum of `100` quickly in a randomized list is relatively high. If you let the difference you want to find grow, then the overhead of building a `set` is rapidly compensated by the speed of `set` lookup.

### Sidenote

As a sidenote, you should not be using the `list` as a variable name as it overwrites the builtin `list`.

Comment: I removed my answer because this is a better explanation but can you avoid the questioner's use of overriding the built-in "list"

Comment: +1 This was a fantastic explanation, and what I was looking for. As for the use of list as a variable name, it was just for the sake of the question. Thanks so much!